# What are the Atom editor icon classes for Project Manager package?

Tags: class, icons, package, atom-editor

What are the classes already provided by Atom editor ([atom.io](http://atom.io)) like icon-squirrel to use in settings talked in [project-manager package](http://atom.io)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer today in [Github Octicons](http://octicons.github.com/). As Atom is from Github, it works very well on its hackable text editor!

Comment: This is helpful, but not perfect--e.g., "icon-squirrel" and "icon-globe" work, but "icon-smiley" and "icon-beaker" don't show up. Is there a file or directory one can look at in the Atom installation that definitively specifies the full list?

Answer (score 1):

The icons are all listed in the `octicons.less` file of the atom repository:

https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/static/octicons.less

Notice however that the latest github version of atom (beta 1.13) is not yet released as of this date. It includes octicons 4.4.

For the current atom version (v1.12), which only includes octicons 2.1.2, go here:

https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/1.12-releases/static/octicons.less

Answer (score 0):

You can see exactly what subset of Octicon icons are used by Atom by viewing the [Atom Styleguide](https://github.com/atom/styleguide).

This package was installed already for me, but if it isn't for you then you can either install it through Atom's package manager interface or via `apm install styleguide` in the command line.

Once installed, open the styleguide in Atom with `cmd-ctrl-shift-g` (macOS) and `ctrl-shift-g` (Windows and Linux) by default. The styleguide will open in a new tab where you can expand or collapse all headings.

Expand `Icons` to see the full list. Helpfully giving you visibility on each icon as well as the string to use to invoke each.

[image: A partial screenshot of the Icon section in the Atom Styleguide]